# Google Sheets Pivot Table - Show totals for only one column in grand total

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that has 1 Row (`ATIVO`), 0 Column and 4 Values columns (`Quantidade`, `Preço Un. Atual`, `Preço Médio` and `Total`).

But I only need the grand total (shown as `Total geral`) from the last `Total` value column.

How can I remove the grand total (`Total geral`) from the others columns?

Similar editable sheet (only need the grand total of the last column): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tMAFh_RI5y6qkuC9ExgNW70Zh_htPqP9MgqxaMfD0ao/edit#gid=2100307022

The table is displayed as follows:[image: pivot table]

And it is set up like this:

[image: configuration]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: sure, @doubleunary. sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tMAFh_RI5y6qkuC9ExgNW70Zh_htPqP9MgqxaMfD0ao/edit#gid=2100307022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a copy of your pivot table where some values in the Grand Total row are replaced with blanks like this:

```
=let( 
  data, G2:L9, 
  grandTotalLabel, "Grand Total", 
  includeInGrandTotal, "STOCK|POSITION", 
  labelCol, index(data, 0, 1), 
  labelRow, index(data, 1, 0), 
  table, 
    filter( 
      data, 
      labelCol <> grandTotalLabel, 
      not(isblank(labelCol)) 
    ), 
  totalsRow, 
    filter( 
      if(regexmatch(labelRow, includeInGrandTotal), data, iferror(1/0)), 
      labelCol = grandTotalLabel 
    ),  
  { table; totalsRow } 
)
```

To add another total to the Grand Total row, add its label in the `includeInGrandTotal`. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tMAFh_RI5y6qkuC9ExgNW70Zh_htPqP9MgqxaMfD0ao/edit#gid=2100307022).

See [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535), [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) and [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).

Comment: grand total celulas aren't editable

Comment: The pivot table in your sample spreadsheet seems to be missing a data source, making it difficult to edit. Edited the answer to add a formula based solution.

Comment: wow. advanced one. thanks!

Comment: I don't know why, but just realized that the grand total sum is wrong

Comment: The grand total in the result is the same as in the pivot table you presented. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.